# Qt browser app with opengl-es2 strange behaviour (not working)

Tags: qt, opengl-es-2.0, qgraphicsview

I have enabled opengl-es2 support in Qt/E and I wanted to make a browser app and the code is :

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QGraphicsView g;
g.setScene(new QGraphicsScene(&g));
g.scene()->setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene::NoIndex);

g.setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
g.setOptimizationFlags(QGraphicsView::DontAdjustForAntialiasing);
g.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
g.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
g.setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignHCenter);
g.setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);
g.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);

g.setViewport(new QGLWidget());
g.showFullScreen();

QGraphicsWebView view;

view.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
view.setGeometry(QRectF(0,0,800,400));
view.show();

g.scene()->addItem(&view);

a.exec();
```

}

I can see google page getting loaded for a fraction of second and then after it disappears.

**Error log paste-bin link ==> http://pastebin.com/bgbQqd1M**

Comment: Did you write the Qt QScreen driver yourself? Is the hellogl_es2 sample application working?

Comment: Yes, I am using Qt4.8 lighthouse and I have changed eglFs platform plug-in for it.

Comment: No I am observing the same issue with hellogl_es2 sample app(after some time it disappears). But I am able to launch texture app perfectly.

Comment: I don't remember I had such problems when I tried QPA with my OpenGL implementation. Are you able to try on another OpenGL implementation/platform?

Comment: I suggest you try with actual Qt embedded, not QPA using the simplegl driver.

Comment: can you enlight me regarding any issues with QPA ?

Comment: Sorry, I only very quickly tested QPA with EGLFS plugin once and everything was working as expected. Only issue I was having was with input devices. Both OpenGL code written in QGLWidget's and Qt API running using the OpenGL paint engine was working correctly I remember. Only thing I can suggest is to try with Qt/E using simplegl driver.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4028/discussion-between-ashish-and-luca)

Answer (score 0):

Ashish,

What changes did you make for eglfs platform plug-in?
I also modified eglfs plugin to make it run on an arm board.

Two place that I changed are:

1. avoid call eglMakeCurrent twice, when EGLDisplay, EGLSurface(Read), EGLSurface(Draw), EGLDisplay not change --- On my board, call eglMakeCurrent twice will cause the program abort.
2. The problem is same as you (QGLShader::QGLShader: 'context' must be the current context or sharing with it.)

   In QtOpengl library, there is a function QGLWidget* qt_gl_share_widget(), that will create a new QGLContext and set it to QPlatformGLContext.

   In bool QGLShaderProgram::bind(), it will check the currentContext with the one in QGLSharedResourceGuard. QGLContext::areSharing(d->programGuard.context(), QGLContext::currentContext()).

To fix this problem.
I add the following code in qeglplatformcontext.cpp

```
#include <QGLContext>

class QEGLFSContext : public QGLContext
{
public:
    bool chooseContext(const QGLContext* shareContext = 0)
    {
        QGLContext::chooseContext(shareContext);   // in QGLContext, this guy is protected
    }
};

void QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent()
{
    QPlatformGLContext::makeCurrent();
    QGLContext * ctx = QGLContext::fromPlatformGLContext(this);
    QEGLFSContext* eglctx = (QEGLFSContext*)ctx;
    static QEGLFSContext * s_ctx = eglctx;
    if (s_ctx != eglctx)
    {
        s_ctx->chooseContext();
    }
    //...
}
```

After use these change, I can run hellogl_es2 and show the animation for show the Qt logo and bubbles well.

But I still have some problem:
QLabel, QMenu... can not show.

Do you have any idea about this problem.
I also got some idea from some guy, qws/simplegl also have these problem.